# What affects how many units you can recruit per turn?

Tags: rome-2-total-war

Is this a flat 3 per each type of military camp you have in a province? For example, I have 1 Auxiliary Barracks, does that mean I can recruit 3 aux barracks units per turn in this province?

Answer (score 1):

A province has a flat 3 recruitment slot, constructing additional unit producing structures will not increase the number of units that can be recruited per turn. However additional recruitment slots could be achieved through the use of edicts and techs.